# "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation" with HTML5 database

Tags: javascript, database, html, google-chrome

I get a error when trying out the following code in Chrome:

```js
var db = openDatabase('foo', 1, 'foo', 1111);

var sql = function(callback){
    db.transaction(function(tx){
        callback(tx.executeSql);
    });
};

sql(function(query){
  // Dose 1 or more querys in same transaction
  query('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO1 (id unique, data)');
  query('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO2 (id unique, data)');
});
```

> Sasy: Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

And I don't really know what that means.

This code however works just fine:

```js
var db = openDatabase('foo', 1, 'foo', 1111);

var sql = function(callback){
    db.transaction(function(tx){
        callback(tx);
    });
};

sql(function(query){
  // Dose 1 or more querys in same transaction
  query.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO1 (id unique, data)');
  query.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO2 (id unique, data)');
});
```

Have you any idea how I can make the first solution works? I want to make it as simple as possible and also within the same transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the case for several host objects in Chrome. `.bind` should work in those cases:

```
callback(tx.executeSql.bind(tx));
```

The point is that the reference to `tx` is lost (the `this` value used internally). You're passing the "generic" function of `SQLTransaction`'s prototype without the information that it should be called on `tx`. `.bind`, however, binds the `this` value correctly, even if you don't call it like `obj.func()` but as a "bare" function call.

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply, that helpt me!